# jQuery onfocus onblur problem

Tags: jquery, onblur, onfocus

I'm having some trouble getting my `onFocus` and `onBlur` events to work properly

Here's what I got

```
var var1

$("input").focus(function() {

  var1 = $(this).val()

if ( $(this).val()==var1) {
       $(this).val('').css({'color': "#000", 'font-style': 'normal', 'font-weight': 'bold'});
   }  
    $(this).css({'background-color':'#d7df23' });    
});

$("input").blur(function() {
   if ( $(this).attr("value")=="") {
       $(this).val(var1).css({'color': "#666", 'font-style': 'italic', 'font-weight': 'normal'});
   }   
    $(this).css({'background-color':'#EEEEEE' });      
});
```

And here's my HTML

```
<input type="text" id="tbTitle" value="Title">

<input type="text" id="tbTitle1" value="Title1">

<input type="text" id="tbTitle2" value="Title2">
```

This works if you don't change the value of the textbox.

Basically I want to get the original value of the input and store it in a var and then if the field is blank put the original value back.

At the moment it is putting the value of whatever is in the textbox on focus

Is there a way to store the original value and only change it to that `onBlur`?

Here's a link to my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YTTD5/)

Comment: Do you want to store the default value of input field in var1 or what? Why don't you like putting at-the-focus-moment-value ?

Comment: If I change the value to `Test` and then click the box again it removes `Test` and then puts it back in if its blank but I want to put the original value i.e `Title` back in

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is my solution...

http://jsfiddle.net/Sohnee/YTTD5/4/

Or in code...

```
var originalValues = new Array();

$("input").focus(function() {

    if (!originalValues[this.id]) {
      originalValues[this.id] = $(this).val()
    }

    if ( $(this).val()==originalValues[this.id]) {
           $(this).val('').css({'color': "#000", 'font-style': 'normal', 'font-weight': 'bold'});
       }  
        $(this).css({'background-color':'#d7df23' });    
   });

    $("input").blur(function() {
       if ( $(this).attr("value")=="") {
           $(this).val(originalValues[this.id]).css({'color': "#666", 'font-style': 'italic', 'font-weight': 'normal'});
       }   
        $(this).css({'background-color':'#EEEEEE' });      
   });
```

Comment: Re `var originalValues = Array();`: 1. It's `... = new Array();`, or if you want to be more concise, ` = [];`. 2. Why use an array when you're not indexing into it with numbers or using any other aspect of its Array-ness? Just use an object.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder - Thanks for spotting my typo, I have corrected that. You may choose to store the values however you wish - the object suggestion is valid.

Comment: My point is that that's what you're doing, using an object. The fact that the object in question is an array is completely unused in your code -- you're not using numeric indexes, the `length` property, or any of the `Array.prototype` functions. You may as well say `new Date()`. But yes, as you say, totally up to the author.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a single `var1`, but multiple text boxes. So the `var1` will be bludgeoned by your entry into another text box when you leave a text box. Also, you're assigning to `var1` before you test the value of the element against it, so the `==` will always be true.

To " get the original value of the input and store it in a var and then if the field is blank put the original value back" you could do something like this:

```
var values = {};

$("input").focus(function() {

    var $this = $(this);

    // Save the value on focus
    values[this.id] = $this.val();

}).blur(function() {

    var $this = $(this);

    // Restore it on blur
    if ($this.val() == "") {
        $this.val(values[this.id]);
    }

});
```

I've left out the CSS stuff above because it wasn't quite clear to me what you wanted to do with it. It's easy enough to add back.

Answer (score 0):

try setting `var var1 = null;` initialy, then when the focus triggers just set it the very first time like `var1 = var1 ?? $(this).val();` it looks like you keep overrriding the value each time, also might want to consider storring the original value as data on the actual object instead of global variable

Comment: again, this will work for one textbox only, you have 3 of them, consider using data attribute per each DOM object

Answer (score 0):

sans the CS stuff.. if we enter a field that has a value back that value up in a 'rel' attribute.
on exit of the field,if the value is empty, copy in whatever might be in the rel attribute, which is either nothing, or is the value that was present on the initial focus.

```
$("input").focus(function() {
 if($(this).val()!=''){
  $(this).attr('rel',$(this).val());
 }
});

$("input").blur(function() {
 if($(this).val()==''){
  $(this).val($(this).attr('rel'));
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You problem is that you storing input value at the moment of focus, not at the moment of it's initial setting.
This piece of code may be useful:

```
var initials ={};
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input').each(function(){
    initials[this.id] = $(this).attr('value');
  });
});

$('input').focus(function(){
  // do whatever you want to
});

$('input').blur(function(){
  if($(this).attr('value')==''){
    $(this).attr('value', initials[this.id]);
  }
  // do other stuff
});
```